# Mostrar resultado de resultset na mesma aba (JSF)

Tags: jsf, resultset

Olá, estou com a seguinte situação: Tenho um botão (pesquisar)que executa um método de pesquisa e retorna os dados na mesma aba já aberta em um `<p:dataTable`.

Após gerar um relatório no `JasperReports` (botão pdf),  que é aberto em uma nova aba , se eu clicar no botão pesquisar novamente, é também aberta uma nova aba, e eu gostaria que a pesquisa fosse sempre mostrada na mesma aba.
No bean onde estão os métodos abaixo o escopo é `@ViewScoped`.
Gostaria de ajuda para entender este comportamento e se possível ajustar o código para abrir a pesquisa sempre na mesma aba.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Método que gera o relatório:

```
public void execute() throws ParseException {
        JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
        configure(report);
        String q = getQueryPrincipal(queryPrincipal)
                + getData(formatDataInicial(dataInicialQuery), formatDataFinal(dataFinalQuery));

        if (arrayCliente.size() > 0) {
            q = q + nomesParaQuery(queryNome);
        }
        if (arrayStatus.size() > 0) {
            q = q + statusParaQuery(queryStatus);
        }
        if (arrayOcorrencia.size() > 0) {
            q = q + ocorrenciasParaQuery(queryOcorrencia);
        }
        if (arrayFormasPg.size() > 0) {
            q = q + formasPgParaQuery(queryFormaPg);
        }
        if (arrayDespesa.size() > 0) {
            q = q + despesasParaQuery(queryDespesa);
        }

        report.setDataSource(q, con);
        System.out.println("Query: " + q);
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

        try {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            report.toPdf(response.getOutputStream());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Método da pesquisa:

```
public List<ConsultaEntrada> teste() throws SQLException, ParseException {
List<ConsultaEntrada> result = new ArrayList<ConsultaEntrada>();
String q = "";
try {
    System.out.println("ANTES:" + dataInicialQuery);
    System.out.println("ANTES:" + dataFinalQuery);
    // formatDataInicial(dataInicialQuery);
    // formatDataFinal(dataFinalQuery);
    System.out.println("Enviando:" + dataInicialQuery);
    q = getQueryPrincipal(queryPrincipal)
            + getData(formatDataInicial(dataInicialQuery), formatDataFinal(dataFinalQuery));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
if (arrayCliente.size() > 0) {
    q = q + nomesParaQuery(queryNome);
}
if (arrayStatus.size() > 0) {
    q = q + statusParaQuery(queryStatus);
}
if (arrayOcorrencia.size() > 0) {
    q = q + ocorrenciasParaQuery(queryOcorrencia);
}
if (arrayFormasPg.size() > 0) {
    q = q + formasPgParaQuery(queryFormaPg);
}
if (arrayDespesa.size() > 0) {
    q = q + despesasParaQuery(queryDespesa);
}
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery(q);

set.beforeFirst();
while (set.next()) {
    ConsultaEntrada consultaEntrada = new ConsultaEntrada();
    consultaEntrada.setCliente(set.getString("cliente_nome"));
    consultaEntrada.setOcorrencia(set.getString("ocorrencia_descricao"));
    consultaEntrada.setFormaPagamento(set.getString("entrada_acidente_forma_pagamento"));
    consultaEntrada.setStatus(set.getString("entrada_acidente_status"));
    consultaEntrada.setDataCriacao(set.getDate("entrada_acidente_data_criacao"));
    consultaEntrada.setDespesa(set.getString("despesa_nome"));
    result.add(consultaEntrada);
}
con.close();
return result;
```

}

```
public void pesquisar() throws ParseException {
    try {
        filtradas = teste();
        for (int i = 0; i < filtradas.size(); i++) {
        }
        System.out.println("Verificando tamanho lista" + filtradas.size());

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

xhtml:

```
<p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:commandButton action="#{simpleReport.execute}" value="PDF"
                        ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>

                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:commandButton action="#{simpleReport.pesquisar}"
                        value="Pesquisar" ajax="false" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>

                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <h:commandLink>
                        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="excel.png" width="30" />
                        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="entradasTable"
                            fileName="clientesFiltrados"
                            postProcessor="#{customizedDocumentsView.postProcessXLS}" />
                    </h:commandLink>
                </p:toolbarGroup>

            </p:toolbar>
```

Comment: Não estou certo do que vou falar, mas se você usar o target="_self"? 

também considere usar o _parent pois há diferença o _parente abre no mesmo frameset, também tem que ver se funciona no prime se não tem que usar o commandLink do JSF


ex:
```<p:toolbarGroup>
    <p:commandButton action="#{simpleReport.pesquisar}" value="Pesquisar" ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target='_self'"/>
</p:toolbarGroup>```

Comment: Olá, deu certo com sua sugestão : `<p:toolbarGroup> <p:commandButton action="#{simpleReport.pesquisar}" value="Pesquisar" ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target='_self'"/> </p:toolbarGroup>`. Havia tentado o `target="_self"`, mas não igual ao seu exemplo. obrigado.

Comment: O que nao entendi é o porque de, se eu clicasse somente no pesquisar abria sempre na mesma aba a pesquisa, mas se antes eu clicasse no botão que gera o pdf e depois clicasse no pesquisar éque abria a pesquisa em uma nova aba.

Comment: Provavelente por causa do escopo da página, uma vez adicionado a árvore HTML ficava valendo para as demais requisições.